# Can you pass const unsigned int4* to a kernel?

Tags: opencl

I have instructions to use:

```
__kernel void myKernel(__global const unsigned int4* data
```

But I get `CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE` whenever I try to build it. However, both of these build without error:

```
__kernel void myKernel(__global const int4* data
__kernel void myKernel(__global const unsigned int* data
```

Comment: Note that the `kernel` tag is for an OS kernel, not for OpenCL / CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"unsigned int" is a valid type, but "unsigned int4" is not. I think what you're looking for is "uint4". See section 6.1.2 of the specification ("Built-in Vector Data Types").